# setOnclickListener for a button help please

Tags: java, android

just getting started with Android development and I can't figure out why this won't work. Here is the error that I am getting (last line before bold block-quote):

```
    package com.ample.ballv2;

    import java.util.Random;

    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.os.Build;

    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
    Button answer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answerbutton);
    answer.setOnClickListener(answerL);
}
private OnClickListener answerL = new OnclickListener(){
public void onClick(view v) {
Random token = random();
int tokenno = token.nextInt(10);
CharSequence ans = "";
switch(tokenno)
{case 0:ans=getString(R.string.msg0);break;
case 1: ans=getString(R.string.msg1);break;
case 2: ans=getString(R.string.msg2);break;
case 3: ans=getString(R.string.msg3);break;
case 4: ans=getString(R.string.msg4);break;
case 5: ans=getString(R.string.msg5);break;
case 6: ans=getString(R.string.msg6);break;
case 7: ans=getString(R.string.msg7);break;
case 8: ans=getString(R.string.msg8);break;
case 9: ans=getString(R.string.msg9);break;
case 10:ans=getString(R.string.msg10);break;

}
Context context = getApplicationContext();
Toast msg = Toast.makeText(context,ans,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
msg.show();
 }
}//error's popping up here
```

**> Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Syntax error, insert ";" to complete FieldDeclaration   MainActivity.java   /8ballv2/src/com/ample/ballv2   line 56 Java Problem**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: It seems you are missing a semi-colon on line 56 of `MainActivity.java`

Comment: Did you try inserting a ';' there? After '}'. Because if there OnClickListener weren't anonymous type, it'd be like that: private OnClickListener answerL = new OnclickListener(); And you have private OnClickListener answerL = new OnclickListener(){...}//nothing here

Comment: i tried deleting the } and adding ; nothing seems to work in fact the moment i did that more errors popped up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just as it says you need to insert a semicolon there since you are declaring a field here. So this is how it should be

```
private OnClickListener answerL = new OnclickListener(){
    public void onClick(view v) {
    ...............
    }//onClick ends here
}; //OnClickListener  ends here
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I tried your code in IDE and the problem - in provided sample - is in variable declaration:

```
private OnClickListener answerL = new OnClickListener(){
     public void onClick(view v) {
           Random token = random();
           int tokenno = token.nextInt(10);
           CharSequence ans = "";
           switch(tokenno) {
                case 0:ans=getString(R.string.msg0);break;
                case 1: ans=getString(R.string.msg1);break;
                case 2: ans=getString(R.string.msg2);break;
                case 3: ans=getString(R.string.msg3);break;
                case 4: ans=getString(R.string.msg4);break;
                case 5: ans=getString(R.string.msg5);break;
                case 6: ans=getString(R.string.msg6);break;
                case 7: ans=getString(R.string.msg7);break;
                case 8: ans=getString(R.string.msg8);break;
                case 9: ans=getString(R.string.msg9);break;
                case 10:ans=getString(R.string.msg10);break;
            }
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            Toast msg = Toast.makeText(context,ans,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            msg.show();
      }
}//here should be ';'
```

It occurs because View.OnClickListener has body with methods. If there were no methods (e.g. you created a

> private class MyOnClickListener implements OnClickListener

(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html)
then it would be like that:

```
private MyOnClickListener answerL = new MyOnClickListener(); //<- semicolon here.
```

You can avoid such in future using autoformating tool (ctrl+shift+f as default in Eclipse/ADT and ctrl+alt+l (or something like that) in AndroidStudio) or declaring class fields strictly before/after methods.

Hope it helps)

Answer (score 0):

`OnclickListener` is an `interface` and you are supposed to create its object like this:

```
private OnClickListener answerL = new OnclickListener(){
    public void onClick(view v) {
        //do stuffs here
    }
 };
```

Please notice the `semi-colon` at the end.